# MLOAD ERROR CODE 4 IN TERADATA

Tags: teradata, mload

I am getting this error in production environment. I want to know the exact cause of this error. Can you please help me when we get this error in teradata mload utilities.

This is what i got when i searched for this error message.

**4:- When there is any warning to the user. For example, if you are trying to create table which is already there 
in the database then it will show you return code as 4.**

I just want to understand in what cases we get this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the log file with this error/warning message in it?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what you said, just a warning. It could be rejected rows going into the ET or UV tables. It could be headers and trailers with a different number of delimiters or record length. Only way to be sure is to check the logs.

If you have no stop turned on and the number of rows rejected is within tolerance you should just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MLOAD Return Codes:

0 = Normal completion
4 = Warning
8 = User error
12 = Severe internal error
16 = No message destination available
```

User error would mean syntax errors in the script.

Internal error would indicate load lock, leftover work tables or log tables, which makes the TD engine believe you are trying to recover, rather than rerun.